# How to elegantly combine a guard statement with a condition?

Tags: swift, guard-statement

I currently have the guard statement:

```
 guard let designationQuota = Defaults.quotas.value?.designationQuota, designationQuota > 0 else {
      return AppDelegate.shared.presentNoDesignationQuotaWarning()
 }
```

however I ***only*** want to do the guard block if the variable `needsQuota == true`. I want to skip the guard statement if `needsQuota == false`. Is there a nicer way of doing this over than an if statement with a return?

EDIT:

How do I simplify this into a single guard?

```
if needsQuota {
  guard let designationQuota = Defaults.quotas.value?.designationQuota, designationQuota > 0 else {
      return AppDelegate.shared.presentNoDesignationQuotaWarning()
   }
}
```

Comment: What variable `needsQuota`, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
guard !needsQuota ||
    (Defaults.quotas.value?.designationQuota.map { $0 > 0 } == true) else {
    return AppDelegate.shared.presentNoDesignationQuotaWarning()
}
```

Comment: @MartinR Yes :p This feels more like a yoga pose

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want to continue execution differently in case your `if` condition fails or in case your `guard` fails, so you cannot really combine them into a single `guard`. However, you could combine the two conditions into an `if` statement by putting the negated version of your `guard` condition in the `if` statement.

```
if needsQuota && (Defaults.quotas.value?.designationQuota ?? 0 <= 0) {
    return AppDelegate.shared.presentNoDesignationQuotaWarning()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn‘t this do the trick?

```
guard needsQuota, let designationQuota = Defaults.quotas.value?.designationQuota, designationQuota > 0 else {
    return AppDelegate.shared.presentNoDesignationQuotaWarning()
}
```